# FullCalendar pass events array as simple argument

Tags: express, fullcalendar

Currently iam trying to pass an array of events in my database as a simple parameter. Below i attach my backend callback, the query document and the pure javascript Full Calendar implementation. So i tried forEach but gives me error . If i pass directly the objects array anaylitically then all works fine, but my issue is that i cannot render events by providing the array variable as argument. I wont like use JSON feed feature because my api is not able to be configurated. Any suggestion welcomed, thank you in advance

```
calendar:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: eventsArray is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

**Express Js Callback**

```
exports.getcalendar=async function (req,res,next){
var bookdata={};
try{
     bookdata=await booking.aggregate().match({resourceID:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}).project({
             'title':'$Project_title',
             'start':'$date_started',
             'end':'$date_finished',
              '_id':0

     })

}catch (error){
    return next(error);
}
finally {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bookdata)));
    res.render('calendar',{databook:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bookdata))});
}


};
```

**bookdata**

```
[
  {
    title: 'prj',
    start: '2021-04-08T20:25:00.000Z',
    end: '2021-04-09T20:25:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    title: 'Proej3',
    start: '2021-04-12T00:58:00.000Z',
    end: '2021-04-13T00:58:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    title: 'May proj',
    start: '2021-05-10T11:00:00.000Z',
    end: '2021-05-11T11:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    title: 'prj',
    start: '2021-04-28T15:00:00.000Z',
    end: '2021-04-28T18:00:00.000Z'
  }
]
```

**FullCalendar Constructor**

```
script.
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (databook) {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                var initdate = new Date();
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    function(){
                        var eventsArray=[];
                        bookdata.forEach(function (element){
                            eventsArray.push({
                            title:element.title,
                            start:element.start,
                            end:element.end  })
                        })
                    },
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    timeZone:'Europe/Athens',
                    initialDate: initdate,
                    handleWindowResize:true,

                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                    },
                    eventTimeFormat:{
                        hour: 'numeric',
                        minute: '2-digit',

                    },
                    eventDisplay:'auto',
                    views:{
                     timeGrid:{
                         formatDateTime:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
                     }
                    },
                    events:eventsArray


                });
                calendar.addEvent()
                calendar.render();

            });
```

Comment: Read this and then implement your event feed in a way that isn't completely nonsensical: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . fullCalendar made a way for this to be easy for you, but your method is complicated and also makes no sense

Comment: I wanted to use my path parameters (resource ID) querying my Database , so every resource has its own calendar('/:resourceID/calendar'), but having nothing similar found i used premium version with resources

Comment: But i think, that my idea has a good basis, it is an another way  to avoid ''paying'' for premium version, so if  someone including me found a solution lets post it here. What is important is  to make you understand what i want to do

Comment: I don't think anything you've just said prevents you from declaring your events feed sensibly in the way I've just described. You can even have multiple event sources, to get the different "resources"

Comment: Your fundamental problem here is that you're not waiting for the events to be downloaded and also eventsArray is out of scope because you declared it in a random anonymous function which probably doesn't even get executed because it's not a valid option to give to fullCalendar

Comment: After a little bit new thoughts, i think that i can implement the idea 
```
'/resources/calendar/bookings/:resourceID'
```
This is the endpoint which takes id of resource and feeds with a json array the calendar at the endpoint
```
'/resources/:id/calendar'
```
My initiall negative thoughts about this implementation is because a have also an  endpoint   ```
'/bookings/resource/:resourceID' ```    Which renders a html page, so i  was thinking something like duplicate endpoints, and how to avoid making endpoints with similar functionality

Comment: Ok. You seem to be talking about something not particularly related to the problem in your question. The design of your endpoint URLs is not related to your inability to download the event data from them correctly in your JavaScript, as far as I can see. I'm not really sure why you're discussing it right now.

Comment: At the moment i was trying to solve a similar problem about canvas js column chart, i had the same problem passing the array of elements. Finally i changed the order of the code and fixes. Tomorrow i will try to apply this solution to my calendar, iam hopefull

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the eventsArray variable inside the calendar variable. You can initialize it right before the calendarEl is created for example

Comment: What does your modified code look like? Try to recreate the issue in a working example and post the link.

Comment: client side cannot understand JSON objects array, so none operation excluding  displaying the properties of objects can  not work